# Internal working of timsort and compareTo() method in Comparable interface

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, comparable, timsort

I have been looking at different articles on internet and everyone mentions that `compareTo()` method would follow natural ordering by default. Let's taken an example.

```
class Car implements Comparable<Car> {
  int id
  Car(int id){
    this.id = id;
  }

  public int compareTo(Car car){
    return this.id - car.id;    //ascending
  }

}
```

It was mentioned that compareTo only specifies if the object being compared with the current object is greater, smaller or equal and it really does n't control the swap of the elements in
sorting. if so, why does the array gets sorted when we just reverse the return type like

```
return car.id - this.id     //descending
```

Here, the main question is if the compareTo purpose is only to find which object is smaller or greater How does the timsort understands if the sorting should be in ascending or descending order. We have n't specified it anywhere. please explain with any example so it would help everyone. Thanks in advance

Comment: It probably uses the comparable to compare two objects and then swaps it internally. What the comparable should return is what you define and that controls ascending, descending.

Comment: The sorting gets to know the sort order by calling your `compareTo` method. If you return a negative number, it means that this car is “less than” the other car, so the *sorting algorithm* will be sort it before the other car. A positive number would mean the opposite. I also find it a bit hard to hold in my head, but I just use it and trust that it works and never got disappointed.

Comment: *`compareTo()` method would follow natural ordering by default.* No, it’s the other way around: The *natural ordering* is *defined* as the ordering given by `compareTo()`.